# customize elfinder file manager

Tags: php

I am using elfinder file manager in one of my project. I am developing my project in PHP. I am new with using this file manager.

Now, I want to execute an SQL query when file will be uploaded and want to put track of each file uploaded with each user separately. So I am not getting that how to customize this thing.

For Example, I am a user and I have registered. Each user has their separate account and they can upload their files there in his/her account.

Now, suppose I am user and uploading 1 image in my account. So when I am uploading my file. I want to insert that file name, size and all other details with user_id in my database table. So I can manage track of each user uploaded files.

Please any one can help me here for this?

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom [callbacks](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-event-API). For example, after uploading make ajax request, which save file parameters to db.

Comment: I mean to say how can I get that file name and other file details?

Comment: elfinder.bind('upload', function(event) { console.log(event); console.log(event.data); });

Comment: can you please help me some more? I am newer so please tell me how to get all details from "console" object?

Comment: it's usual javascript object

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware how to get data from javascript object. please guide me for that by example